# GKE Ambassador http -> https redirect, health check issues

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, health-check, google-cloud-load-balancer, ambassador

I am following this tutorial https://www.getambassador.io/docs/latest/topics/running/ambassador-with-gke/ and I am having serious issues with http -> https redirect.

- I can not edit health check port on GKE, it is configured as serving port by default and cant be changed
- If I create new healthcheck, after applying `Host insecure.action: Redirect`, backend's hc goes back to default one. if default hc is deleted, it gets recreated. If I force by some way my custom hc, it does not work again, in pod logs I see this `"GET /ambassador/v0/check_ready HTTP/1.1" 301`
- if I set `insecure.action: Redirect`  in Host http -> https works for couple of seconds before LB health check brings everything down

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`insecure.action: Redirect` in Host should be `Route`

Additionally custom health check needs to be created:

```
kind: BackendConfig
metadata:
  name: my-backendconfig
spec:
  healthCheck:
    checkIntervalSec: 10
    timeoutSec: 10
    healthyThreshold: 2
    unhealthyThreshold: 2
    type: HTTP
    requestPath: /ambassador/v0/check_ready
    port: 8080
```

and added to ambassador.yaml

```
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: ambassador
  annotations:
    cloud.google.com/backend-config: '{"ports": {"8080":"my-backendconfig"}}'
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    service: ambassador
```

Ingress should disable http:

```
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: basic-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: "myip"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: "false"
spec:
  tls:
    - secretName: my-self-managed-cert
  backend:
    serviceName: ambassador
    servicePort: 8080
```

This will create only HTTPS LB which will perfectly work and now we need http -> https redirect.

Simply go to Load Balancing screen and create 1 more load balancer (without backend) which will only redirect http to https.